# geth node not seeing pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions

I'm running a geth node locally on goerli network in sync mode. I use the following command to boot the node :

```
geth --goerli --syncmode "light"
```

My txpool never list pending transactions, but I can see activity in almost every block : [goerli etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/)

What Am I missing ? I guess every new transaction are broadcasted to the network to get in the new mined block. Why is my node never seeing one ?

I tried to submit a transaction to the network through my node. This one appeared in my local txpool and was mined ...

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is answered in this issue https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16216

In short, nodes running in "light" mode are only capable of seeing their own transactions.