# Geth light node returns 0 pending / queued transactions despite being fully synced. Cannot reasonably access tx-pool data

Tags: nodes, external-api, txpool

The two following commands are inputted into the Javascript live console, but return identical results from HTTP requests (whose methods appear slightly different).

The node is fully synced as indicated in the following result and the block count is keeping up as a synced node would be expected.

```
> eth.syncing
false
```

However the transaction pool remains empty (meaning the `txpool.content` command is useless).

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 0
}
```

This is the incantation I use to start the node.

```
~geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node/ --cache 18000 --txlookuplimit 0 --syncmode light --rpcapi txpool_content --txpool.globalslots=2500 --txpool.globalqueue=250 --http --http.api eth,net,web3,txpool console
```

Strangely, from within the console, I can use the following incantation to view pending transactions.

```
eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions[0])
```

But this does not help me access the tx-pool from outside the console, nor is it clear how to access the whole data structure rather than a single index even from within the console. Trying to show the whole structure (omitting the index) gives this result:

```
> eth.getTransaction(eth.getBlock("pending").transactions)
Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash
        at web3.js:6405:37(47)
        at web3.js:5115:62(37)
        at <eval>:1:19(9)
```

I was under the impression that `txpool.status` was global - if it is the case that the `txpool` namespace is for local transactions only, how does one view the global txpool and/or access it from outside the console?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` returns? That `eth.syncing` returns false doesn't necessarily mean it has finished syncing it might be disconnected from others peers and it isn't able to continue syncing.

Comment: It returns a new, increasing number each time - so it appears to be keeping up.

Comment: I haven't used a geth instance in light mode to check pending transactions, perhaps they aren't supported in that mode since they can't be verified.

Comment: Well, as per my post, it is still possible to see pending transactions.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem, Have you solved it? In addition, my node is not 100% sync and I don't understand why currentBlock: 8775607,
highestBlock: 8775711,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my source still applies, light node [`cannot maintain a pool of pending transactions`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16216) (except its own transactions).

> A light client only maintains its own transactions. It cannot maintain
> a pool of pending transactions, since it cannot check the validity of
> those transactions (without the state, which is costly to pull from
> the network for every single tx).

Edit:

Also, kind of already asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87614/geth-node-not-seeing-pending-transactions) last year. So it seems still true.